# Eliminé el contenido de /tmp

Tags: linux, wordpress, web, wordpress-plugin, centos7

a fin de borrar archivos temporales en desuso opté por eliminar la carpeta /tmp.
Ahora obtengo un problema al querer descargar o actualizar cualquier plugin de wordpress.
Servidor: CentOs7
PHP: 8FPM
Ejemplo:

```
*Falló la actualización: Descarga fallida. fopen(/tmp/advanced-cron-manager.2.5.2-ee4atO.tmp): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
*Falló la actualización: Descarga fallida. fopen(/tmp/all-in-one-seo-pack.4.4.6-cb89R7.tmp): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
*Falló la actualización: Descarga fallida. fopen(/tmp/antispam-bee.2.11.4-jXAWZi.tmp): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
*Falló la actualización: Descarga fallida. fopen(/tmp/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp-D2BHDU.tmp): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Ya intenté darle permisos de chmod 777 a la carpeta y también es seguro que la carpeta existe.
Mi web puede verse normalmente y funciona bien, pero quiero poder actualizar y descargar plugins.

Yo me imagino estos archivos no están de manera nativa en /tmp, es decir, cada vez que descargo un plugin el instalador se crea en dicha carpeta y se ejecuta. O al menos asi me lo imagino yo.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

`tmp` es un directorio especial... necesita uno de esos bits especiales para funcionar como se requiere..... fíjate:

```
$ ls -ld /tmp/
drwxrwxrwt 24 root root 20480 sep 16 15:38 /tmp/
```

Se necesita el ultimo bit con un `t`.... tendrías que ejecutar:

```
chmod +t /tmp
```

Y obvio, también debe tener los owners apropiados:

```
chown root:root /tmp
```

Comment: Di los permisos que mencionas y aún así sigo recibiendo errores al momento de querer actualizar plugins :/.

drwxrwxrwt 8 root root 170 sep 16 19:15 /tmp/


Me pareciera seguro es algo de permisos dentro de la carpeta tmp, estuve toda la tarde creando, eliminando y editando y no tuve caso... Alguna otra idea?

Comment: SOLUCIONADO.
Con cambiar de PHP 8.0 FPM A 7.4 FPM y nuevamente volver a 8.0 FPM Y reiniciar el servidor, se soluciono solo :=)